# MongoDB repository - Aggregation - Mongo Template dont work

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-repositories

I try some aggregation with MongoDB repository. I used these tutorials: https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-aggregation-grouping-example/ and https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.group. But none of them don't work and I don't know where is problem. My repository look like :

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction;

import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationResults;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<MongoStudent, String> {

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    Aggregation agg = newAggregation(project("studium"), unwind("studium"), group("studium").count().as("n"),
            project("n").and("studium").previousOperation(), sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "total"));

    AggregationResults<MongoTable> results = MongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "studium", MongoTable.class);
    List<MongoTable> mappedResult = results.getMappedResults();

}
```

and MongoTable look like :

```
class MongoTable {

@Id
BigInteger id;
@Field
String skratka;
@Field
String zaciatok_studia;
@Field
int n;

...getter,setters, etc
```

Problem is that MongoTemplate give me error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method aggregate(Aggregation, String, Class<MongoTable>) from the type MongoTemplate` and when I try change all imports to static imports it give me : `The static import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate must be a field or member type` and when I change `MongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "studia", MongoTable.class);` to `mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "studia", MongoTable.class);` it give me : `The blank final field mongoTemplate may not have been initialized` I don't know what else try. Any help?

There is config :

```
@EnableMongoRepositories
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.nosql")
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration{

    static MongoClient mongo = null;

      @Bean("applicationTemplate")
      @Qualifier("applicationTemplate")
      public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(
          final MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter, final MongoClient mongoClient) {
        final String databaseName = mongo.getDatabase("mynosqlproject").getName();

        final MongoDbFactory dbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, databaseName);
        return new MongoTemplate(dbFactory, mappingMongoConverter);
      }

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        // Creating a Mongo client
                MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(
                        "mongodb://xxx:xxx/mynosqlproject");
                 mongo = new MongoClient(uri);
                 return mongo;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
                return mongo.getDatabase("mynosqlproject").getName();
    }

}
```

**UPDATE :** So I have new classes in my project.

```
public class AggregationRepository {

    Aggregation agg = newAggregation( unwind("studium"), group("course","start").count().as("n"), sort(Sort.Direction.DESC,"n"));

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    AggregationResults<MongoTable> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "studium",MongoTable.class);
    List<MongoTable> mappedResult = results.getMappedResults();


}
```

And service class.

```
@Service
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository repository;
    private AggregationRepository repository2;

    public void saveData() {
            ....

    }

    public void findStudentsFromYear() {
        ....

    }

    public void findStudentsDromCourse() {
        ......
    }

    public void AggreagationTable() {
        List<MongoTable> mappedResult = repository2.mappedResult;
        mappedResult.forEach(System.out::println);

    }

}
```

Problem is that it still don't work. It give me `nullpointer` exception at `System.out.println(repository2.mappedResult);` It look that problem is in AggregationRepository. Aggregation agg work fine, but mongoTemplate is null. what I miss ?

Comment: Can you put some code of Mongo config?

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-tutorial

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-projections-aggregations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change interface StudentRepository to simple java class and remove extends CrudRepository and add method returns:

```
List<MongoTable>
```

You try to inject a bean into the interface hence you got an excetpion:

```
The blank final field mongoTemplate may not have been initialized
```

Comment: ok, i try create new class for this aggregation, but i use CrudRepository for another operations, so I cant remove it.

Comment: This is not good think way. CrudRepository extends interface to take it some default method and extends to another new. If you want to use interface (for example save/delete etc) you have to create another interface and aggregate function you have to store in this class.

Comment: well, i have new classes, but mongoTemplate still have some problem ...

Comment: What problem? Any exceptions or does not loading data?

Comment: don't load data. MongoTemplate was still null. But I solve it. I move MongoTemplate to StudentService

Comment: Yes exactly.  MongoTemplate is a bean (component) and must be injecting into real object (component) such a StudentService. Not into interface.